# I need to implement ignite into existing NODE js project. I read documentataion of apache ignite but could not find out how to start

Tags: sql, node.js, angularjs, ignite

I need to implement apache ignite in existing NODE js project. I read apache ignite documentation but unble to find from where to start and how to change queries from existing one. I create a NODE in java but how to link that node with node js thin client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried copying & modifying some of Node.JS examples, such as [SqlExample.js](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/nodejs/examples/SqlExample.js)?

More are available through [Ignite Node.JS docs section](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/nodejs-thin-client#section-running-an-example).

Comment: Thank you for your respone.
I read above documentation and tried to run existing node js files and they are working fine. but when i create my own code. it gives me error.

Comment: Please share that error along with your code in a separate dedicated question.